# Drop down css not working with knockout bind option

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, semantic-ui

The issue is that when I bind options to the dropdown, "ui dropdown" makes it disappear and nothing is in the cell in my browser(it dosent use the css properly in jsfiddle). If i remove that css then i see the out of the box dropdown.

creating a table with a viewmodel collection and want a dropdown of values for the individual risks

```
//part of the viewmodel
var ViewModel = {
Collection: ko.observableArray(),
availableRisks: ['L', 'H'],
```

using

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

doesn't help.
Sample code that dosent work with the dropdown:

http://jsfiddle.net/7vh2t33m/2/

Comment: When you're using a plugin that moves/replaces/removes DOM elements you can't expect knockout to keep working. You'll have to make sure the plugin and knockout work together via a custom binding. Also, if you want two-way binding for an input `value`, you'll have to use observable properties.

Comment: You're using very old semantic and don't have it set up in a way that would work regardless of Knockout. See http://jsfiddle.net/7vh2t33m/3/

Comment: Dosent seem to work on mine,  i'm using an ajax call to get the values for binding.   All I see it the dropdown without any values.  I tried calling $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown(); after the bindings and after the ajax call.   for each viewmodel in the array I have some subscribe properties, not sure if its interfering or something.

Comment: adding $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh'); after doing the ajax call worked

Answer (score 0):

There are bindings for jQuery UI and knockout, use them. http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/

Rule of thumb, in a knockout application nothing may touch the DOM except knockout, or without informing knockout. Therefore, mixing knockout with jQuery UI without anything that bridges the gap between them will not work.

Taken from the example in [knockout-jqueryUI selectmenu binding documentation](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/selectmenu.html):

```
var ViewModel = function () {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([
      { id: '1', text: 'First' },
      { id: '2', text: 'Second' },
      { id: '3', text: 'Third' },
      { id: '4', text: 'Fourth' }
  ]);
  this.value = ko.observable('1');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and in the view

```html
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<input type="radio" name="radios" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked: $parent.value" />
<!-- /ko -->
<br/>
<select data-bind="value: value, selectmenu: { width: 300 }, options: items, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'text'">
</select>
<br />
```